# coarser/finer comparison for relative topology and norm topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose $p\in [1, \infty]$. Show the relative topology on $l^p(\mathbb{R})$ induced from the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}= \Pi_{l=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{R}$ is strictly coarser than the $p$-norm topology on $l^p(\mathbb{R})$, but the relative topology on $l^p(\mathbb{R})$induced by the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is strictly finer than the $p$-norm topology on $l^p(\mathbb{R})$.

Attempt:

We know that $l^p(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$.

By definition the relative topology is $S = \{ V \cap l^p(
\mathbb{R}): V \in T \}$, where $T$ is the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$.

To show it's coarser than the $p$-norm topology, we want to show that there exists an open ball $B$ in $l^p(\mathbb{R})$ such that $B \notin S$. But I'm not sure how to find such open ball.

Now let $S' = \{ V \cap l^p(
\mathbb{R}): V \in T \}$, where $T$ is the box topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$.

I'm not sure what to do to show the $p$-norm topology is strictly coarser than $S'$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show the first part and leave pointers for the second part.

It is easy to see that any basic open set of the relative product topology contains an open $p$-ball from the $p$-norm topology (**justify this yourself**). But, consider the unit $p$-ball in $\ell^p(\mathbb{R})$: $B_p(0, 1) = \{x \in \ell^p(\mathbb{R}) : \|x\|_p < 1\}$. This is not open in the product topology induced on $\ell^p(\mathbb{R})$. To see this, consider the sequence $(0)_{i = 1}^\infty \in B_p(0, 1)$. And let
$$U = \Big(\prod_{i = 1}^\infty (a_i, b_i)\Big) \cap \ell^p(\mathbb{R}),\ (a_j, b_j) = (-\infty, +\infty)  \text{ for all but finitely many $j \in I_{\text{finite}}$}$$ be any basic open set of the induced product topology containing $(0)_{i = 1}^\infty$. Thus, $a_i < 0 < b_i$. *Then $U$ is never contained in $B_p(0, 1)$*. Indeed, choose any of the infinitely many $n \in \Bbb Z_+ - I_{\text{finite}}$ such that $(a_n, b_n) = (-\infty, +\infty)$. And consider the sequence $(\delta_{n,i})_{i = 1}^\infty$ (i.e. it is $1$ at index $n$ and $0$ elsewhere). Then $\|(\delta_{n,i})_{i = 1}^\infty\|_p = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{i = 1}^\infty|\delta_{n,i}|^p} = \sqrt[p]{|\delta_{n,n}|^p} = 1$. So $(\delta_{n,i})_{i = 1}^\infty \not\in B_p(0, 1)$. But $(\delta_{n,i})_{i = 1}^\infty \in U$ easily because obviously $(\delta_{n,i})_{i = 1}^\infty$ converges in the $p$-norm and $a_i < 0 < b_i, i \neq n$ while $-\infty = a_n < 1 < b_n = +\infty$.

The situation changes with the induced box topology. Again, it is not hard to see the induced box topology contains the $p$-norm topology (**justify this yourself**). But, consider the following basic open set from the induced box topology:
$$
U = \Big(\prod_{i = 1}^\infty (-4^{-i/p}, 4^{-i/p})\Big) \cap \ell^p(\mathbb{R})
$$ Again, $(0)_{i = 1}^\infty \in U$ but no open $p$-ball $B_p(a, R), a \in \ell^p(\mathbb{R}), R > 0$ containing $(0)_{i = 1}^\infty$ is in $U$. To see this, first simplify: any such $B_p(a, R)$ also contains another ball centered at $(0)_{i = 1}^\infty$: $B_p(0, r), R > r > 0$ (**why?**). Now, the sequence $(\frac{1}{2}r\ 2^{-i/p})_{i = 1}^\infty \in B_p(0, r)$ (**why does this converge in the $p$-norm? why is it in the ball?**). However, $(\frac{1}{2}r\ 2^{-i/p})_{i = 1}^\infty \not\in U$ (**find some $j \in \Bbb Z_+$ large enough such that $4^{-j/p} < \frac{1}{2}r\ 2^{-j/p}$; why is this enough?**).

Comment: Hi may I ask for  the first part, why is it enough to show that $U$ is not contained in $B_p(0,1)$? Thanks!

Comment: @cciirrcclllee A subset $A$ of a space $(X, \tau)$ is open iff every point $a \in A$ admits an open neighborhood $U$ of $\tau$ that is entirely contained in $A$. Therefore, to show $B_p(0, 1)$ is **not** open in the product topology induced, you have to show there is some point $a \in B_p(0, 1)$ such that **no** open neighborhood of $a$ is inside $B_p(0,1)$. In this case, $a = (0)_{i = 1}^\infty$.

Comment: To show that any basic open set of the relative product topology contains an open $p$-ball from the $p$-norm topology, does it just follow from the definite of the relative topology? Thanks!

Comment: @cciirrcclllee No. You have to explicitly consider such a basic open set and make an small enough $p$-ball that fits inside.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. Why do we need to show that any basic open set of the relative product topology contains an open $p$-ball from the $p$-norm topology. Is it for showing that the relative space induced by the product space $\subseteq$ $p$-norm topology? If so, why is it enough to show  that any basic open set of the relative product topology contains an open $p$-ball from the $p$-norm topology? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is for concluding relative product space $\subseteq$ $p$-norm topology. Also, you have to show any basic open set $U$ contains an open $p$-ball $B_p(x, r)$ *at every point $x \in U$*. Then $U$ would be open wrt $p$-norm topology because $U = \bigcup_{x \in U}B_p(x, r)$. You can ask this as a separate question if you are having trouble showing this.

Comment: @cciirrcclllee again, I think you should ask this subfact as a separate question. Constructing an $r$ and proving it works is not something possible in a comment.